# LFU алгоритм логика работы программы в JAVA - Алгоритмы

Tags: java, алгоритм, кэширование, map

есть код в java работы LFU-cache алгоритма. 
Не могу понять логику работы вот сам код:

Класс LFU-cach

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class LFUCache<K, V> implements Cache<K, V> {

    private final LinkedHashMap<K, Node> storage;
    private final int capacity;

    public LFUCache(int capacity) {
        if (capacity <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Capacity should be more than 0");
        }
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.storage = new LinkedHashMap<>(capacity, 1); 
    }

    @Override
    public V get(K key) {
        Node node = storage.get(key);
        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return node.incrementFrequency().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        doEvictionIfNeeded(key);
        Node oldNode = storage.put(key, new Node(value));
        if (oldNode == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return oldNode.getValue();
    }



    private void doEvictionIfNeeded(K putKey) {
        if (storage.size() < capacity) {
            return;
        }
        long minFrequency = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        K keyToRemove = null;
        for (Map.Entry<K, Node> entry : storage.entrySet()) {
            if (Objects.equals(entry.getKey(), putKey)) {
                //no eviction required cause element already exists, we just need to replace it
                return;
            }
            if (minFrequency >= entry.getValue().getFrequency()) {
                minFrequency = entry.getValue().getFrequency();
                keyToRemove = entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        storage.remove(keyToRemove);
    }

    private class Node {
        private final V value;
        private long frequency;

        public Node(V value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.frequency = 1;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public long getFrequency() {
            return frequency;
        }

        public Node incrementFrequency() {
            ++frequency;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Node [value=" + value + ", frequency=" + frequency + "]";
        }

    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "storage = "+ storage + ", capacity=" + capacity ;
    }
}
```

ну и самый простой раннер для его запуска

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Runner {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        LRUAlgoritm<String, String> lruAlgoritm = new LRUAlgoritm(2);
        lruAlgoritm.put("1","1");
        lruAlgoritm.put("2","2");
        lruAlgoritm.put("3","3");
        lruAlgoritm.put("4","4");


        System.out.println(lruAlgoritm);
        LFUCache<String, String> lfualogoritm =  new LFUCache<>(3);

        lfualogoritm.put("1", "1");
        lfualogoritm.put("2", "2");
        lfualogoritm.put("3", "3");
        lfualogoritm.put("4", "4");
        lfualogoritm.put("5", "5");
        lfualogoritm.get("1");
        lfualogoritm.get("2");
        lfualogoritm.get("1");
        System.out.println(lfualogoritm);
    }

}
```

у меня возникает вопрос почему когда прохожу дебагом 
в 30 строке `Node oldNode = storage.put(key, new Node(value));`
`oldNode` принимает значение `null`, ведь здесь в `storage` передаются вводимые значения?

если ввести lfualogoritm.get("10"); то здесь node = storage.get(key); присваивается нул. и дальше выход(т.е. контроль запрашиваемого ключа в кэше). А вот зачем здесь проверка if (oldNode == null) { return null; } не понимаю, пустые значения ("","") принимает и также получаем null. Если аргументов нету, вообще не компилится. Для чего это ограничение?

огромное спасибо @etki, догнал, то что я не догонял)))) 
Это нужно при oldNode не равном null, когда равно какому-нить LFUCache$Node (id=37) ))) Т.Е. когда такой ключ уже есть в кэше, мы значение value не записываем снова, а берем из кэша.

Но тогда правильно ли я понимаю, что при вставке нового ключа(вернее ключа с таким значением которое уже есть в кэше) само фреквенси(frequency) , если было больше единицы, становится снова 1?

Comment: Вы пробовали почитать описание работы этого метода в map? Это стандартный контракт.

Comment: @ etki по переводу  т.е. должно выдать предыдущее значение map или null.  либо при предыдущем нулевом значении map  с ключом null, если это поддерживается реализацией

Comment: сам перевод: Предыдущее значение, связанное с ключом, или null, если не было отображения для ключа. (Нулевой возврат также может указывать на то, что ранее связанная карта null с ключом, если реализация поддерживает нулевые значения.)

Comment: все равно не пойму зачем здесь нужно проверять на null ? что эта проверка здесь дает, и когда она может быть другой кроме как null? а потом еще и get, и здесь наоборот выдает код node LFUCache$Node  (id=37). при каких условиях он может быть другим.?

Comment: задать значения, что бы получился другой вариант не получается((

Comment: если ввести  lfualogoritm.get("10"); то здесь node = storage.get(key); присваивается нул. и дальше выход. А вот зачем здесь проверка  if (oldNode == null) {
            return null;
        } не понимаю, пустые значения ("","")  принимает и также получаем null,  если аргументов нету вообще не компилится. Для чего это ограничение?

Comment: если там null, то как на нем можно буджет вызвать getValue?

Comment: @etki вот этот момент  понятен  зачем гетВалуе, что здесь вообще происходит?

Comment: @etki           doEvictionIfNeeded проверяет перегрузку кэша, если размер превышает сапасити, то лезем в мапу и там проверяем наличие этого ключа, если есть выходим. Если нет то проверяем вторым условием  чтобы найти мин фрекуенси и найдя последнее значение с минимально фрекуенси удаляем его ключ storage.remove(keyToRemove).

Comment: @etki Удалили. а затем используем  Node oldNode = storage.put(key, new Node(value)); в сторейдж добавляем новое вводимое значение. Т.Е. после doEvictionIfNeeded в  oldNode всегда будет null т.к. мы всегда будем всталять новые значения в storage. когда же он не будет null? что я тут упускаю?

Comment: Я ей-богу не понимаю, как вы упускаете эти моменты. Если doEviction удалил, то там ничего не будет. А если он НЕ удалил?

Comment: @ etki А если не удалил, то oldNode LFUCache$Node  (id=37) )))  Т.Е. когда такой ключ уже есть мы значение не записываем снова а берем из кэша. Тогда правильно ли я понимаю, что при вставке нового ключа(вернее ключа с таким значением которое уже есть в кэше) само фреквенси , если у нас было больше единицы, становится снова 1?